# Cascading properties in CSS

Tags: css

I am not able to understand the cascading in CSS.

```css
.lastBtnOfSection > button {
    color:red;
}

.sectionBtn {
    color:black;
}
```

Here both are buttons contained in `.lastBtnOfSection`.

`.sectionBtn` is the class of the button. According to cascading the later should override but it worked only when I changed `.sectionBtn` to `.lastBtnOfSection > .sectionBtn`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because the selector `.lastBtnOfSection > button` is [more specific](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) than `.sectionBtn`.

The selector `.lastBtnOfSection > button` has a [specificity calculation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) of 11 whereas the selector `.sectionBtn` is 10 (class selectors have a specificity of 10 and type selectors are 1).

As pointed out by [Gray in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370780/cascading-properties-in-css/29370811#comment46922515_29370811), [this is a nice tool](http://specificity.keegan.st/) for automatically calculating these values.

Comment: You beat me to it. Here's a cool site I just discovered that says exactly what you said. http://specificity.keegan.st/ (screenshot for convenience: http://i.imgur.com/zvOxBUY.png )

Comment: great article. You made my life easier.
@Gray +1 for the tool.